# How to use env variable to lock multiple stages in declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two nodes, each connected to multiple devices, which I want to lock as resources.
I have grouped the devices into two pools, with the label name matching the NODE_NAME.

As far as I understand, locking multiple stages is only possible by setting the lock in the options block. This however means, that I can not use the env.NODE_NAME variable to set the label.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        lock(resource: null, label: env.NODE_NAME, variable: 'DEVICE', quantity: 1)
    }
    stages {
        stage('Installation') {
            steps {
                echo "Install ${env.DEVICE}"
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo "Test ${env.DEVICE}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a smart solution for this or do I have to lock each stage and pray that no race conditions occur?

Comment: Could you fix it? I don't seem to be able to use "env.NODE_NAME" either.  Maybe it has to happen within a stage...?  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately not. As a workaround I made a properties file in which NODE_NAME and EXECUTOR_NUMBER are mapped to a device configuration. That ensures, that no jobs can be started, if there is no free executor / device. Not sure if this is somehow applicable for you.